# Is it possible for onload to return an error?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have the following function to get the dimension (width and height) of an image file that is uploaded:

```js
let target = document.getElementById('test');

function getImageDimension() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let imgElement = new Image();
    imgElement.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(target.files[0]);
    
    imgElement.onload = () => {
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(imgElement.src);
      resolve({
        width: imgElement.width,
        height: imgElement.height
      });
    };
  });
}

target.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //Some other stuffs before I actually get the dimension
    //I actually validate the file type here before trying to get the dimension of the file
    //For the sake of an example, I'll resolve immediately
    resolve('test');
  })
  .then(() => {
    return getImageDimension();
  })
  .then((dimension) => {
    console.log(dimension);
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e.message);
  });
});
```

```html
<input id = "test" type = "file" accept = "image/*">
```

Now the above doesn't seem to return an error. However, I'm curious to as what happens if the `onload` part of `imgElement` never finishes for some reason? The promise of my `getImageDimension()` will never be resolved. Do I need to add a `reject` block on my `getImageDimension()` function?

Also, if `onload` does fail somehow, what may be the cause(s)?

**EDIT**

I seem to have found one thing that may cause `onload` to fail: if I remove the validating section on my `promise` block in `addEventListener(...)`, I can try uploading a `exe` file and it the promise will never be resolved on my `getImageDimension()` part. How do I fix this so that it `rejects`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onload` can't "return an error", instead, [`onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/image#a-onerror) is invoked if there is an error loading the image, and `onload` is never called.

Any number of things can prevent the image from loading, and therefore prevent `onload` from being called, including any 4xx or 5xx error response from the server or a failure to connect to the server at all, or the server's response not being a valid image.

Comment: I see! A mere addition of `imgElement.onerror = () => { //Some reject block };` is sufficient to make sure that the Promise gets either resolved or rejected, then?

Comment: Yes, `imgElement.onerror = reject` is probably sufficient.

Comment: Technically correct, however there may still be an *error* in that the browser is for instance unable to set a width or height to said image. [Here I force it](https://jsfiddle.net/m60qsrux/), but IE is known to do it with all svg images that do not have absolute height and width attributes.

Comment: @Kaiido That's not a problem, because `onload` is still invoked, and the promise will be resolved. The worry here is that the promise is never resolved or rejected.

Comment: That is not an `Error`, but still an *error*  and definitely a problem. For instance at least in Firefox, CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage will throw an IndexSizeError if you ever pass such an image. Most imaging tools will also consider any image with either a width or a height of 0 as invalid. OP may be interested in handling such cases by revoking their Promise, even though it's caused neither by a Network nor a Decoding Error (and thus doesn't trigger the onerror event)

Comment: You should use addEventListener instead of .onError = [...]
Otherwise you will override all default (and previous) listeners.